# Setting a CGPDFObjectRef to value

Tags: iphone, quartz-2d, cgpdfdocument

Does anyone have a way to change the information contained in a CGPDFObjectRef? Basically since CGPDFObject can represent any of the subtypes (CGPDFInteger, ie.) you would think you could *set* an existing CGPDFObjectRef that is type integer to an integer; however, I have played with this for quite some time with no success and was wondering if anyone had come across a solution that i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the CGPDF API is pretty much read-only.

Comment: so ive come to see, so you don't know of anyway possible? even reading it into a NSObject type or what have you and then somehow setting the original back? That was my idea but i cant seem to get it to work.